# When does ID_FUNCCAP_EXTEND_MEM take effect?

Tags: memory-management, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Will the ID_FUNCCAP_EXTEND_MEM capability take effect only after the app is signed and certified? Or will also work when side loading a xap to an unlocked device?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact answer to your question but you might be able to figure it out by checking the **ApplicationWorkingSetLimit** value using the **DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue(String)** method as mentioned on this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681682(v=vs.105).aspx.  If it comes back with 380MB as the answer (for high-memory phones) then it's likely it takes effect when the app is installed/executed.

Get more information on DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.deviceextendedproperties.getvalue(v=vs.105).aspx

You can find a list of extended property names here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.deviceextendedproperties(v=vs.105).aspx